# Why does the check for file type for sharing fail in universal windows UWP share application?

Tags: c#, windows, uwp, uwp-xaml, windows-community-toolkit

I am trying to build a universal Windows application that will act as a share target, that is it will come up in the share charm like so:

[image]

Now I made a UWP and the manifest looks like this :
[image]

I added the code behind for this like so:

```
        {
            if (args.shareOperation.Data.Contains(StandardDataFormats.Text))
            {
                string text = await args.shareOperation.Data.GetTextAsync();

                // To output the text from this example, you need a TextBlock control
                // with a name of "sharedContent".
                //sharedContent.Text = "Text: " + text;
            }
        }
```

However, the check always fails even if I am exporting the txt file. What am I getting wrong here?

Comment: What is the item that you want to share? Is it a .txt file or it is something else like string?

Comment: The txt file. And I want to increase the functionality to include all file types.

Answer (score 0):

Ok got it, the answer is that the file is in StorageItem type and not in Text type.